# Performing actor lookup with Akka actorFor

Tags: java-8, akka

I have the following Akka actor:

```
public class MyActor extends AbstractActor {
  protected Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
      return receiveBuilder()
          .matchAny(message -> {

            String myFullName = self().path().toString();
            String myName = self().path().name();
            ActorRef reincarnatedMe = context().actorFor(self().path().name());
            String reincarnatedFullName = reincarnatedMe.path().toString();
            String reincarnatedName = reincarnatedMe.path().name();

            log.info("myFullName: {}", myFullName);
            log.info("myName: {}", myName);
            log.info("reincarnatedFullName: {}", reincarnatedFullName);
            log.info("reincarnatedName: {}", reincarnatedName);

          }).build();
  }
}
```

At runtime it produces this output:

```
05:43:14.617 [MySystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO myapp.actors.MyActor - myFullName: akka://MySystem/user/MyActor
05:43:14.623 [MySystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO myapp.actors.MyActor - myName: MyActor
05:43:14.623 [MySystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO myapp.actors.MyActor - reincarnatedFullName: akka://MySystem/user/MyActor/MyActor
05:43:14.623 [MySystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO myapp.actors.MyActor - reincarnatedName: MyActor
```

My *understanding* was that `context().actorFor(...)` doesn't create a *new* actor, rather it finds an existing actor that matches the path/string you provide and returns a reference to it.

However, it appears that in my code above, `self()` becomes the **parent** of `reincarnatedMe` as evidenced by `myFullName` simply being "`MySystem/user/MyActor`" whereas `reincarnatedFullName` is "`MySystem/user/MyActor/MyActor`"...

Am I reading this right? If so, how can I invoke `context().actorFor(...)` (or any other method for that matter) such that `myFullName` becomes the same as `reincarnatedFullName` (so that `self()` and `reincarnatedMe` reference the same actor? And if I'm not reading this right, why is `myFullName` different than `reincarnatedFullName`?

---

#### Update:

```
public class AnotherActor extends AbstractActor { ... }

// Inside MyActor#createReceive:
ActorSelection anotherActorSel = context().actorSelection("AnotherActor");

anotherActorSel.tell(new SomeMessage(), self());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `ActorContext.actorFor(String)` is deprecated in favor of `ActorContext.actorSelection(String)`. This method returns an ActorSelection, but you can still send a message to an ActorSelection (such as an Identify, which response with an ActorIdentity message automatically).

The documentation for the `actorFor` method says that, "Absolute URIs like akka://appname/user/actorA are looked up as described for look-ups by actorOf(ActorPath)." I can't find documentation on an `actorOf(ActorPath)` method, but the other `actorOf` methods state they create new actors, so I suspect this does the same. The behavior you've found is likely the reason for the deprecation -- or because it was deprecated and the methods used for something else.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Crawford (+1) please see my update above. Regarding the use of `actorSelection(...)`, any chance you could confirm two things: **(1)** that I can send *any* message/object to an `ActorSelection` instance, not just baked-in ones such as `Identify` that ship with Akka, and much more importantly, **(2)** that the returned `ActorSelection` finds and reuses (does **not** create!) an existing actor based on the provided selection path? Thanks again so much!

Comment: The tell() method for ActorSelection takes an Object, so any message can be sent, and I know from my own use of ActorSelection that it reuses an existing actor, if there is one. If there is no actor matching the ActorSelection, the messages go to the dead letter box.

Comment: You rock! Thanks Rob!